# Build and deploy a golang Docker image using Terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform

I am trying to setup auto deployment in Terraform to Docker of my golang server.

I have it working if I am deploying manually, but can't get the terraform config working.

Here is what I have.

```
resource "docker_image" "terraform_golang" {
  name = "terraform_golang"
  build {
    path = "./../"
    build_arg = {
      tag : "golang-server"
    }
    label = {
      author : "Bill"
    }
  }
}

resource "docker_container" "terraform_backend" {
  image = docker_image.terraform_golang.latest
  name  = "Terraform_Backend"
  env = [ "database=172.19.0.3:3306" ]
  ports {
    internal = 8080
    external = 8080
  }
  network_mode = "bridge"
  networks_advanced {
    name = "golang-server"
  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
│ Error: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
│
│
│
│   with module.terraform.docker_image.terraform_golang,
│   on terraform\backend.tf line 2, in resource "docker_image" "terraform_golang":
│    2: resource "docker_image" "terraform_golang" {
```

Here is my manual deployment cmd, which is working:

```
docker build . -t golang-server 

docker run --network=golang-server --name=golang-server --env database=172.19.0.3:3306 --expose=8080 -p=8080:8080/tcp golang-server
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.18

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src

COPY . .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...


EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["golang-server"]
```

My folder structure is setup such that my terraform files are in a subfolder, in a module, I hope this doesn't mess with anything:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"path" only changes the context path, not the path where to find the docker file. Honestly feels like a bug since the docker command defaults to PATH/Dockerfile as a docker file path, but that's how the terraform plugin currently works.

What you need is to add a dockerfile parameter to point to the actual Dockerfile;

```
resource "docker_image" "terraform_golang" {
  name = "terraform_golang"
  build {
    dockerfile = "../Dockerfile"
    path = ".."
    build_arg = {
      tag : "golang-server"
    }
    label = {
      author : "Bill"
    }
  }
}
```